# How do I create a custom git/bash script?

Tags: git, awk, git-bash

I'd like to make it so that if I type `git recent` in my terminal, it actually runs:
`git reflog | egrep -io "moving from ([^[:space:]]+)" | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40}$' | head -n5`
giving me the 5 most recent git branches I've checked out to.

Bonus points: I'd like to add an argument, so that if I type `git recent 20` it runs: `git reflog | egrep -io "moving from ([^[:space:]]+)" | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40}$' | head -n20`
giving me the 20 most recent git branches I've checked out to.

Also, any readings/tutorials series to recommend in to better understand how this script works, and how to write custom bash scripts? Thanks.

Comment: Are you tried to create alias for it?

Comment: It can be an alias or anything, as long as it achieves the goal above. I didn't expect I could include the 'git' keyword in an alias since it's a reserved term.

Comment: I think you can create a bash script that gets your argument and puts it in your command and run it. After you create this script you can create an alias for it so whenever your run git recent this will run something like this: `bash script.sh 20`

Comment: Git has support for aliases running custom scripts: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases. For using the most recent branch feature I would recommend leaving out the `-n5` and just passing that to `git recent -n50`

Comment: FWIW : my version of it : https://gist.github.com/LeGEC/a75473eb5575a5c6814efafcace80957 (I invoke mine by typing `git wip`)

Answer (score 8):

If you create a script, accessible from your path, and name it : `git-foo`, then :

```
git foo arg1 arg2 ...
```

will invoke that script, with arguments.

It's the advised way if fitting your command on one single line for a `git` alias becomes too complicated.

Comment: I didn't know about that... Is it a documented git feature ?

Comment: yes, but I am still searching for the reference ... :)

Comment: There's a mention in the main man page: "Supported groups are: builtins, parseopt (builtin commands that use parse-options), main (all commands in libexec directory), others (**all other commands in $PATH that have git- prefix**)"

Comment: They also show up under "external commands" for `git help -a`.

Comment: The best I could come up with was BenjaminW.'s mention hidden in `man git`. There is also a set of standard git commands which are actually implemented as `git-something` scripts : under linux, look at the content of `/usr/lib/git-core/`. Currently (git v2.33), commands such as `git submodule` or `git bisect` are external scripts. Fun fact : you can also see a lot of symbolic links to `git` itself, for commands that once were implemented as scripts, and have since been integrated to a core `git` binary.

Answer (score 2):

are you aware of [git aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) ?

Permanent aliases are stored in your `.gitconfig` file, usually in your home directory.

You can edit this file and append:

```
[alias]
    recent = "!git reflog | egrep -io 'moving from ([^[:space:]]+)' | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40}$' | head -n5"
```

You would use it like so `git recent`

---

**What does ! mean ?**

As you may have noticed the `!`. I will explain what's what.
A standard alias such as: `cm = commit -m` will when used go from `git cm` to `git commit -m`.

But as a matter of fact you can tell git to replace the whole line.
If I were to write `cm = !commit -m` when used the command would go from `git cm` to `commit -m`

That's what the `!` does.

---

**Bonus point**

It is way more ugly but still worth checking:

```
[alias] 
    bonus = "!f() { \
             git reflog | egrep -io 'moving from ([^[:space:]]+)' | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40}$' | head -n$1; \
             }; f"
```

You would use it like so `git bonus <number of branches>`

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative with a simple git alias :

```
$ git config --global alias.recent '!f() { for i in $(seq 1 $1); do git name-rev --name-only --exclude=refs/tags/\* @{-$i}; done; }; f'

$ git recent 3
some-branch
other-branch
yet-another-branch
```

You can also sort it easily with `git recent <n> | sort -u` if needed.

Comment: `${1:-10}` instead of `$1` will supply a default 10 count.

Comment: @jthill I often have default arguments in my aliases but oddly I didn't think of it here. Valuable improvement, thank you. Why the `:`, though? Shouldn't it be `${1-10}`?

Comment: Matter of taste in a corner case that doesn't occur here, so it's a force-of-habit thing with me, the empty-or-unset lets you explicitly take the default even with following arguments if this took further args you could, `git recent '' further args` and still get the default count.

Comment: btw name-rev appears to take multiple args, `git name-rev --etc @{-{1..${1:-10}}` works as well as the loop for me. I *really* want dash and company to get brace expansion, it's just too expressive to do without.

Comment: Ah. In a function you have to eval to get the expansion done. `f() { eval git name-rev --name-only --exclude=refs/tags/\* @{-{1..${1:-10}}}; }; f`

Answer (score 0):

`egrep | awk | awk | egrep | head` is really an anti-pattern that should almost certainly just be done with a single `awk`, but that's not terribly relevant here.  You can easily write a function to wrap git and do what you want.  Put the following in your bash startup scripts:

```
git() {
        case "$1" in
        recent)
                command git reflog | egrep -io "moving from ([^[:space:]]+)" |
                        awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40}$' | head -n${2-5}
        ;;
        *)
                command git "$@"
        ;;
        esac
}
```

Now, if the first argument to the function is `recent`, the reflog pipe will be executed, using the 2nd argument as the number of lines to show (defaulting to 5).  If the first argument is not `recent`, the args will be passed unchanged to `git`.