# macOS git create custom command

Tags: git, macos, shell, github

I would like to create a custom command on macOS for git that when run like this:

```
git create username/project
```

Do this:

```
git init && 
git add . && 
git commit -m "Init" && 
git branch -M main && 
git remote add origin git@github.com:REPOSITORYNAME.git && 
git push -u origin main
```

Where instead of `REPOSITORYNAME` there must be `username/project`.

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: There are many tutorials if you look around. One is https://www.shellscript.sh/.

Comment: Naming your script `git-create` and putting it on your `PATH` will allow you to also invoke it as `git create`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69105623/how-do-i-create-a-custom-git-bash-script

Comment: `git config --global alias.create '!f() {git init && git add . && git commit -m "Init" && git branch -M main && git remote add origin git@github.com:${1}.git && git push -u origin main}; f'` could work, but you'd also need to ensure that the GitHub repo has been created before you run it.